# Clusters on Databricks is an empty screen?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I just started using Databricks and have registered for a trial account. When I click on the clusters page, though, this is the screen I see:

[image]

Ive tried restarting my computer and accessing the page through safari and google chrome, but I still only see a blank page. Its been several hours since I started my account, and I have it setup so that it is linked to my AWS account. Any idea of what's going on here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue unfortunately. Are you running this on Azure? I'm using AWS for my instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24 hours went by and then I was able to access clusters. I can't tell you what changed, maybe I just needed to wait a bit longer for my deployment to load.

Comment: Glad to know you are able to access the cluster page. You can now accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Azure Databricks** and able to load the clusters page without any issues.

[image]

**Steps to troubleshoot this issue:**

**Step1:** To identify the browser issue, you may try the following steps and let us know.

- Clear “Cookies and Cache data” of your browser.
- Private Mode (New InPrivate Window).
- Try in different browser.

**Step2:** Check out the Databricks Status [Page](https://status.databricks.com/) provides an overview of all core Databricks services, if any outages in the region where you have deployed the Databricks workspace.

**Step3:** If you have a support plan, open a support request.
Support Guide [Azure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026305/sql-contact-microsoft-azure-support) | [AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/support.html)